# OpenSource Documentation Software

Tags: php

I'm looking for some documentation software to which I can use to.. Well, basically. Add my own PHP snippits, tutorials and stuff.

I have seen one before, I can't remember the name though. So I do know they exist.

Comment: any wiki script will do it, like http://www.mediawiki.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a wiki, i've been a user of [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) when they had it on a subject in the univerisity, and is good enough. If you don't want an installation, you could simply use [github](https://github.com/) which will give you a software repository and the other things you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org), is open source well documented, has several tutorials and it's really simple to use. You document your code in "JavaDoc" style, run your code through Doxygen and you get a nice HTML or PDF manual of all your classes, methods or comments.